# how to call attributes of more than one class in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I am studying oojs and I have here the summary of the classes, to demonstrate the problem. Because the classes are large with many attributes and validations. I need the `book` class to receive the attributes of the `Author` class (name) and the `Category` class (category), but in my test I get undefined for my imports in the `Book` class. What could I have done wrong? I appreciate the help!

class author

```
export default class Author {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    set name (name){
        if(name === '')
            throw new Error (`this field cannot be empty`)
            this._name = name;
    }
    
    get name (){
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

class category

```
export default class Category {
    constructor(category){
        this.category = category;
    }

    set category (category){
        if(category === '')
            throw new Error (`this field cannot be empty`)
            this._category = category;
    }
    
    get category (){
        return this._category;
    }
}
```

class book

```
import Author from './Author.js'
import Category from './Category.js'

export default class Book{
    constructor(name, title, category){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
    }
    set name(name){
        if(name instanceof Author)
           this._name = name;     
    }
    set category(category){
        if(category instanceof Category)
           this._category = category;     
    }
  
    set title (title){
       if(title === ' ')
            throw new Error (`this field cannot be empty`) 
        this._title = title;
    }
    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }
    get category(){
        return this._category;
    }
    get title(){
        return this._title;
    }
}
```

test

```
import Book from './Book.js';

try{
    const newBook = new Book(' Anne', 'Design UX/UI', 'Design');
    console.log(`saved ${newBook.name} ${newBook.title} ${newBook.category}`)
}catch(err){
    console.log(`err ${err}`)
}

//saved undefined Design UX/UI undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `new Book()` need to be instances of the `Author` and `Category` classes, not strings. So you have to do:

```
const author = new Author('Anne');
const cat = new Category('Design');
const newBook = new Book(author, 'Design UX/UI', cat);
```

And when you're printing the properties, you need to access their `name` properties as well.

```
console.log(`saved ${newBook.name.name} ${newBook.title} ${newBook.category.category}`)
```

Alternatively, you could define `toString()` methods in the other classes:

```
export default class Author {
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    set name (name){
        if(name === '')
            throw new Error (`this field cannot be empty`)
            this._name = name;
    }
    
    get name (){
        return this._name;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

export default class Category {
    constructor(category){
        this.category = category;
    }

    set category (category){
        if(category === '')
            throw new Error (`this field cannot be empty`)
            this._category = category;
    }
    
    get category (){
        return this._category;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.category;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, Barmar! Thank you for your answer! The output has this error [object Object]
` console.log(`saved ${newBook.name}, ${newBook.title}, ${newBook.category} `)`

//saved [object Object], Design UX/UI, [object Object]

Comment: You need to print the names of the author and category, not the objects themselves. I've updated the answer.